# AVPlayer inside UITableViewCell with other Views auto layout

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, avplayer

I have a UITableViewCell that has a UILabel and an AVPlayer that plays videos from online that I need to implement. The problem is that AVPlayer that [Apple gives](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayerlayer) cannot use auto layout to correctly show the video.

I believe there are methods for implementing a UIView for a mixed constraint and frame layout. I think there is more to this question though: there seems to be an issue with the fact that the video does not load on init.

UITableViewCell

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class PlayerView: UIView {
    var player: AVPlayer? {
        get {
            return playerLayer.player
        }
        set {
            playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
            playerLayer.player = newValue
        }
    }

    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer {
        return layer as! AVPlayerLayer
    }

    override static var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return AVPlayerLayer.self
    }
}

class CustomTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    let titleView = UILabel()
    let containerView = UIView()
    let playerView = PlayerView()
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {super.init(coder: aDecoder)}
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        titleView.text = "Title"
        titleView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        contentView.clipsToBounds = true
        containerView.clipsToBounds = true
        contentView.addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        //contentView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
        var lg = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.topAnchor),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.leadingAnchor),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.trailingAnchor),
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.bottomAnchor)
        ])

        containerView.addSubview(titleView)
        containerView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 17, bottom: 15, right: 17)
        lg = containerView.layoutMarginsGuide

        playerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.addSubview(playerView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            titleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.topAnchor),
            titleView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.leadingAnchor),
            titleView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.trailingAnchor),
//            titleView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.bottomAnchor),

            playerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.bottomAnchor),
            playerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.leadingAnchor),
            playerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.trailingAnchor),
            playerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
}
```

I've setup a UITableView in my view controller, but the main point is the UITableViewDataSource cellForRowAt:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReuseableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CustomTableCell
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")
    let avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url! as URL)
    cell.playerView.playerLayer.player = avPlayer
    return cell
}
```

But I don't see the video. Obviously, there is a function like willLayoutSubviews or something along those lines, but how would I break the constraint of the title view to constrain with the AVPlayerLayer or something like that so I CAN see the video?

In general, how would I see that AVPlayer or any player inside of a custom UITableViewCell that has other auto layout views?

---

Edit 1: The answer @ugur gave is correct since the AVPlayer needs to resize. Expanding the view using leadngAnchor and trailingAnchor cannot solve the problem since that only expanded was the size of the current view was.

Using a centerXAnchor, widthAnchor, and heightAnchor will work. A centerXAnchor will center your player in the view.

Comment: Can you share some screenshot of how it is showing?

Comment: @Niraj_iOS I only see text. Video won't appear. In fact, even if it did which it didn't, if the user reoriented the device, then the videos would become a disaster.

Comment: You can put the `UIView` in storyboard and add player on that view programatically

Comment: @Yoomama Please take a look at the following answer I hope that will get your problem solved.

Comment: @Yoomama did you managed to check the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell autolayout how the playerView height will be calculated.
You can try the following options:

1. set a constant height to playerView

   ```
   playerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
   ```
2. or set a aspect ratio to playerView

   ```
   playerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: playerView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0)
   ```

So autolayout will know how to position your playerView. otherwise playerView height will be 0.

**Recommendations:**

Don't create `AVPlayer` in `cellFor` instead do it in cell init or `awakeFromNib` (if storyboard is used). So `AVPlayer` will be reusable too. Just reset the setup with new url or `playerItem`. You can also use play or pause depending on ur case. But just don't recreate the `AVPlayer` every time `cellFor` is called.

Comment: If I set both height and width anchor (along with a top and bottom anchor (idk???)), will the video become distorted?
Additionally, I put it in cellFor because I'm linking a server with this and would need some kind of index to link an array of data with the cell using cellFor. How else would I go about it?

Comment: Do you mind giving an example of how I would instantiate in the init of the cell rather than the cellFor? Pretty inexperienced with AVKit

Answer (score 0):

So your main problem here is you are not able to see your player inside the cell.  I have modified some of you code and then it's showing and playing the video also.

NOTE: It's very basic code and I am sure you will be able to improve it further as per your requirements.

Your `PlayerView` stays same what changes is as follows. I have added new method `configureFor` which will only get the url as parameter and the setup the player.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableCell
    let url = URL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")
    cell.configureFor(url!)
    return cell
}
```

Following is your code for the cell.
Here i have moved the UI setup code to a common function `commonInit()` and then made use of it as follow.

```
    class CustomTableCell: UITableViewCell {

    let titleView = UILabel()
    let containerView = UIView()
    let playerView = PlayerView()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        titleView.text = "Title"
        titleView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        contentView.clipsToBounds = true
        containerView.clipsToBounds = true
        containerView.backgroundColor = .orange
        contentView.addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        //contentView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
        var lg = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.topAnchor),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.leadingAnchor),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.trailingAnchor),
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.bottomAnchor)
        ])

        containerView.addSubview(titleView)
        containerView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 17, bottom: 15, right: 17)
        lg = containerView.layoutMarginsGuide

        playerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.addSubview(playerView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            titleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.topAnchor),
            titleView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.leadingAnchor),
            titleView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.trailingAnchor),
            //            titleView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.bottomAnchor),

            playerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.bottomAnchor),
            playerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.leadingAnchor),
            playerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.trailingAnchor),
            playerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func configureFor(_ url: URL) {
        let avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url)
        self.playerView.playerLayer.player = avPlayer
        self.playerView.playerLayer.player?.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it does not work. The worry that I had perceived was that leadingAnchor and trailingAnchor. Know that this UIView is not a normal UIView. You have to increase the size of the AVPlayer, and that required the height and width anchor.

Comment: Okey coz I tried locally it’s was showing the player and also the video was playing

Comment: Sorry, all I see on the simulator is the orange cell on iOS 13 iPhone 11 Pro Max. Check the answer that @ugur gave. Not to be rude, but your init is not what helps.

Comment: Moving the init into a custom function wouldn't enlarge the PlayerView. You need these anchors in order to show the video. Fitting in a video on after it was initialized wouldn't work for any view unless you reinstantiate the view.

Comment: The change is in also how you configure the cell see the cell for row at index path

Comment: Yes, I've utilized that function. Does not work. Please read me comments.

Comment: Okey to add to it my cell height was 300 for demo purpose

Comment: But never mind as long as you are able to solve the problem all good

Comment: It's all good Harshal. I recommend you do a tutorial on UITableView because setting a height instead of an estimatedHeight is not a good idea. In the future, do NOT mix a frame height with auto layout. Additionally, don't explicitly set a cell height unless it's known that all cells have the same height, but even still, it's not a good idea. Use the default automatic Dimensions for the heights.